# How to reduce permissions required for Google Sign In

Tags: javascript, html, google-app-engine, google-plus

I'm putting a google signin button on my site.

When I go to "sign up" to google with the button from my the following permissions are asked to be approved :

[image]

However, I do not need to know basic profile info or a list of people in circles. Because this can be a deterent from users signing up - how do i remove this request?

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to modify the scopes your app uses. Our app stores our required scopes like this:

```
scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email']
```

Your app is requesting scopes that require those permissions.

*Note:* https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email is depreciated, use https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read instead.

Comment: Thanks. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read has been enough for my purposes.